# Mercurial Web Interface Broken Links

Tags: windows, iis, mercurial

I'm installing mercurial on a W2K IIS 6 server.

I've got it to the point where I can browse a list of my repositories at http://localhost/hgrepo/hgwebdir.py.  My hgweb.config contains [path]hgrepo = c:\hgrepositories**

But when I click on one of the repository name.  In this case its Babbet, I get the same page but when I examine the address I see this:

http://localhost/hgrepo/hgwebdir.py/hgrepo/hgwebdir.py/Babbet/

If I click on the repositories list page again I get

http://localhost/hgrepo/hgwebdir.py/hgrepo/hgwebdir.py/hgrepo/hgwebdir.py/Babbet/Babbet/

is there a configuration that I must set?

Comment: Which Mercurial version are you using?
Does 'hg serve' give you a sensible repository browser on http://localhost:8000/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google "Mercurial IIS Patch"

I recompiled the mercurial source and have been successful installing it on Windows 2008 with IIS7.